# synchronized not work ,still java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, hashset, synchronized

I have the following Java code:

But the synchronized not work well, Help!

java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException     at
>   java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1442)    at
>   java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1466)     at
>   java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:196)     at
>   Main.m(Main.java:68)  at Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:25)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

```
public class Main {

    public static Set<Object> objectSet = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        new Thread(()->{m();}).start();
        new Thread(()->{add();}).start();
     }   
    public static void add() {
        while (true){
            objectSet.add(new Object());
        }

    }
    public static void m(){
        while(true){
            try {
                synchronized (objectSet) {
                    List a = Arrays.asList(objectSet.toArray(new Object[0]));
                    System.out.println(a.size());
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can't synchronize (java.util.ConcurrentModificationException)

Comment: just use `public static Set<Object> objectSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>())`

Comment: `synchronized` is cooperative.  It is meaningless to use it in `m()` but not in `add()`.  (Also, every Java SE collection class has a constructor that copies another Collection, so you can just write `List<?> a = new ArrayList<Object>(objectSet);`.)

Answer (score 0):

The writers should also synchronize on the same object

Change the `add` method as

```
public static void add() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (objectSet) {
            objectSet.add(new Object());
        }
    }

}
```